# Using mocking with .NET Reflection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, system.reflection

I am trying to attempt mocking on some reflection (code below). I have been advised to use NSubstitue but I am struggling on how to implement this and to get it started.

At the moment my test stubs are simply like the one below, however on the build server these obviously fail as the DLLs are not present.

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void CanGetStudentXml()
    {
        var student = new ReadStudent();

        var results = student.GetStudentXml();

        Assert.AreNotEqual(string.Empty, results);
    }
```

Can anyone give me any pointers on how I should go about doing this? Do I need to create mock assemblies? If so, based on the one below, how would I achieve that?

Also is Nsubsitute the best for the job, or would moq be better suited? Which would be the best mocking framework to use?

Sample code:

```
namespace MokPoc
{
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var students = new ReadStudent();
        var results = students.GetStudentXml();
        var contacts = students.GetTelephoneXml();
    }
}

public enum ReflectedAssembyType
{
    SimsProcessesTpPersonStudent,
    SimsProcessesTpPersonContact
}

internal class ReflectedAssemblyFactory
{
    public static ReflectedAssemblyBase GetReflectedAssembly(ReflectedAssembyType reflectedAssembyType)
    {
        ReflectedAssemblyBase value = null;

        switch (reflectedAssembyType)
        {
            case ReflectedAssembyType.SimsProcessesTpPersonStudent:
                value = new SimsProcessesTpPersonStudent("ThirdPartyProcesses.dll");
                break;
            case ReflectedAssembyType.SimsProcessesTpPersonContact:
                value = new SimsProcessesTpPersonContact("PersonContacts.dll");
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }
}

internal abstract class ReflectedAssemblyBase
{
    private string path = string.Empty;
    private string type = string.Empty;

    public string Path
    {
        get { return this.path; }
        set { this.path = value; }
    }
    public string Type
    {
        get { return this.type; }
        set { this.type = value; }
    }

    public object InvokeFunction(string name, object[] args)
    {
        var assemblyToLoad = Assembly.LoadFrom(this.path);
        var typeToLoad = assemblyToLoad.GetType(this.type);
        var methodToInvoke = typeToLoad.GetMethod(name, args.Select(o => o.GetType()).ToArray());
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToLoad);
        return methodToInvoke.Invoke(obj, args);
    }
}

internal sealed class SimsProcessesTpPersonStudent : ReflectedAssemblyBase
{
    public SimsProcessesTpPersonStudent(string assembly)
    {
        this.Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Program Files\Zoosk", assembly);
        this.Type = "SIMS.Processes.TPPersonStudent";
    }
}
public class ReadStudent 
{
    public string GetStudentXml()
    {
        var contacts = ReflectedAssemblyFactory.GetReflectedAssembly(ReflectedAssembyType.SimsProcessesTpPersonStudent);
        return  (string)contacts.InvokeFunction("GetXmlStudents", new object[] { DateTime.Today });
    }

    public string GetTelephoneXml()
    {
        var contacts = ReflectedAssemblyFactory.GetReflectedAssembly(ReflectedAssembyType.SimsProcessesTpPersonContact);
        return (string)contacts.InvokeFunction("GetXmlTelephone", new object[] { DateTime.Today });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm very confused why this is being downvoted. Other than briefly asking a question whether moq would be a better choice than Nsubsitute, what are people objecting to? I disagree that this should be closed as opinion-based. Why is the OP being downvoted?

Comment: I've not downvoted, but it seems to me that personal preference will play a heavy part in the answers you receive and hence the close votes.

Answer (score 2):

I have refactored you code to understand what you are trying to test, it seems like you had a lot of classes to do something that seems could be the responsibility of one class, the heart of what you are trying to do is in GetStudentAttributes, I would create a test.dll with a class and public method that returns some strings and then run an actual method to test, in that case you are not using a stub or mock but it is a valid test to ensure your code works. You should also test GetTelephoneXml and GetStudentXML but the only thing you are really testing there is that GetStudentAttributes is inkoved with the appropriate parameters, so when GetStudentXML is called you invokeGetStudentAttributes with "ThirdpartyProcesses.dll" and "GetXmlStudents".

Depending on the framework you use the solution to testing will be different, with Rhynomocks you will have to make the methods virtual to allow the proxy to inherit and invoke your methods, but you can certainly test that the method was called and that the parameters are what you expect, I haven't used nSubstitute, so not sure how to do it there but if the framework is decent you should be able to test those calls and the parameters.

One of the first things that you should do when using driven development is to start by writing the tests first, making sure it fails, making it pass and refactor, usually when you try and retrofit tests to existing code it could get really hard, there are some good resources out there about unit testing, this is a great book about it [http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-Development-By-Example/dp/0321146530](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530), but in my experience when something is hard to test it usually tells you that your code is too complex or something can be improved, once the code is simplified or fixed testing is usually not a problem.

Good luck and hope this helped a bit!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MokPoc
{
    internal class Program
    {
           private static void Main(string[] args)
           {
                var students = new ReadStudentsService();
                string results = students.GetStudentXml();
                string contacts = students.GetTelephoneXml();
           }
    }


    public class ReadStudentsService
    {
        private const string ProgramFilesZooskDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Zoosk";
        private const string SimsProcessesTppersonstudent = "SIMS.Processes.TPPersonStudent";

        public string GetStudentXml()
        {
            return GetStudentAttributes("ThirdPartyProcesses.dll", "GetXmlStudents");
        }

        public string GetTelephoneXml()
        {
            return GetStudentAttributes("ThirdPartyContacts.dll", "GetXmlTelephone");
        }

        public string GetStudentAttributes(string dllToUse, string methodToExecute)
        {
            var fullpath = Path.Combine(ProgramFilesZooskDirectory, dllToUse);
            var args = new object[] {DateTime.Today};
            var assemblyToLoad = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullpath);
            var typeToLoad = assemblyToLoad.GetType(SimsProcessesTppersonstudent);
            var methodToInvoke = typeToLoad.GetMethod(methodToExecute, args.Select(o => o.GetType()).ToArray());
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToLoad);
            return (string) methodToInvoke.Invoke(obj, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respones Fabian. The code I posted is a trimmed down version of the original code. The enum, and switch statement contains 27 references to different DLLs.I though it would be easier if I trimmed it down for the purposes of showing it here